# Ошибка при попытке вывести ASCII код нескольких символов, введенных пользователем

Tags: python, ascii

Попросите пользователя ввести произвольную строку.
Выведите коды всех символов строки, введённой пользователем.

```
str_1 = input('Введите строку: ')
print(ord(str_1))
```

Здесь выводит только ASCII код одного символа а дальше выводит ошибку:

> TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Нужно помочь - объяснить как вывести ASCII код нескольких символов, введенных пользователем!
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `print(*[ord(s) for s in input('Введите строку: ')], sep='\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы пытаетесь преобразовать в код целую строку, а эта функция работает только с буквами, поэтому вызывайте ее побуквенно:

```
for char in input('Введите строку: '):
    print(ord(char))
```

ну или если нравится изврат и компактность:

```
print(*[ord(char) for char in input('Введите строку: ')], sep='\n')
```

вот так покороче:

```
print(*map(ord, input('Введите строку: ')), sep='\n')
```